# Ionic list buttons resize when right icon display

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I dynamically show / hide icons on the right side of the list. However, when the icon shows, the `ion-item` scales up a little bit.

Any idea how to fix this? Definitely not a nice UX like that.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-divider color="primary">
      Select
    </ion-item-divider>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let property of properties; let i = index" (click)="propertySelected(property)" >
      {{ property }}
      <ion-icon *ngIf="propertySet[i]" name="checkmark" item-end></ion-icon>
    </button> 
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // implementes css for ion-icon
ion-icon{
   position: absolute or fixed;
   width: 10px;
   right: 10px;
}
```

have to make css the fixed icon, with the size of the better than what you have to submit

Comment: But that would mean to size all `ion-icon` s to `10px`... ?

Comment: `ion-icons` have a `small` / `large` property